# Bind WPF DataGrid Directly to EntityCollection<T>

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework, entity-framework-4

I understand the way wpf supports automatic updates of DataGrids and Listboxes (ie adding new items and removing removed ones) is with the `INotifyCollectionChanged` interface that ObservableCollection implements.  For some reason however I seem to be having complete success binding to an `EntityCollection<T>` from EntityFramework, which does not seem to implement `INotifyCollectionChanged`.  Is there some other way WPF is doing this?

I'd just like to know how this is working.

**EDIT**

Here's the relevant portion from the answer.  The short form is that it "just works" with WPF and WinForms bindings.

> EntityCollection currently does not
>   implement INotifyCollectionChanged,
>   which is the “new” standard interface
>   for notifying collection changes.
>   However, the binding list that you can
>   obtain for EntityCollection (and
>   which databinding will typically get
>   when you pass and EntityCollection
>   as a data source) is an IBindingList
>   which has its own “old” standard way
>   of notifying of collection changes
>   (namely, the ListChanged event). In
>   general, WinForms and WPF databinding
>   knows how to deal with this interface.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently there was a [bug filed](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/507563/entitycollection-should-implement-the-inotifycollectionchanged-interface) on this, but it was closed as "by design" (atleast not for .NET 4).

As [this post](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-ZA/adonetefx/thread/a1e37fd3-5011-44a1-9577-fa812462e274) explains, EntityCollection effectively uses the "old" or WinForms way of list change notification, which uses IBindingList. While WPF uses the "new" INotifyCollectionChanged interface.

This [blog post](http://blog.nicktown.info/2008/12/10/using-a-collectionviewsource-to-display-a-sorted-entitycollection.aspx) explains a good way to wrap an EntityCollection with a custom ListCollectionView, which you can assign to the ItemsSource property.

Comment: Your link gave me the answer, but you quoted the wrong part!  :)  +1 nonetheless.  Thank you.

Comment: From the 'this post' by Diego B Vega linked above, "the binding list that you can obtain for EntityCollection<T> (and which databinding will typically get when you pass and EntityCollection<T> as a data source) is an IBindingList... an EntityCollection<T> and its binding list are always synchronized both ways for both deletions and additions"

Comment: @Kimberly, yeah, thanks - I already updated my question with that answer.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You might have a look at the *EntityObservableCollection* which can be found in the **BookLibrary** sample application of the **[WPF Application Framework (WAF)](http://waf.codeplex.com)**. This one ensures that the WPF Binding recognizes all updates.